# Date convert error show on combobox "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'."

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a Combobox in vb.net which is connected with SQL 2008. This Combobox retrieve 'Date' value from SQL table as '2019-08-02' format. But now I want to Show it as '02-Aug-2019' on a MsgBox. But I got this error.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type System.IFormatProvider'.

I've tried to convert the Date format on combobox Click event by using following code :

MsgBox(Trim(ComboDate.Text.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")))

I expect the output of 2019-08-02 to be 02-Aug-2019, but it show a 'GREEN LINE WARNING on "dd-MMMM-yyyy" and show the Error on run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse your string to a date and back to a string:

```
Dim fromDateStr as String = "2029-08-02"
Dim asDateTime as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDateStr, "yyyy-MM-did", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim toDateStr = asDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-2019")
```

It might be simpler to just have the database format your date into a string when the query is run. Modern versions of SQL server support FORMAT function(you really should upgrade your db):

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-MM-yyyy') as datestr
FROM ...
```

Older ones we have to hack it:

```
select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 106), ' ', '-') as datestr
```

Hopefully you've stored your date as a date, not a string

Comment: I use this code,   < Dim asDateTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ComboDate.Text)
        Dim toDateStr = asDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") >